# Which file loader is needed and how to configure it in Nuxt?

Tags: configuration, nuxt.js, webpack-loader

I am new to Nuxt and I the following error I can't seem to solve. What kind of loaders is needed for this file type and where and how do you configure it in Nuxt?

```
> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:212)                         
> friendly-errors 14:15:59 You may need an appropriate loader to handle
> this file type, currently, no loaders are configured to process this
> file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders | export default
> function define(runtime, observer) { |   const main =
> runtime.module();
> >   const fileAttachments = new Map([["portrait_reduced.jpg",new URL("./files/a65c8bd3d98eb3773d1410b4a23de730ab4eebfccaf1b4717e1ac05598c39e2532985c5601726d137c688ea17ff2c30461a0e1e10d4e634c83b81ecb0f368fcb",import.meta.url)]]);
> |   main.builtin("FileAttachment", runtime.fileAttachments(name =>
> fileAttachments.get(name))); |  
> main.variable(observer()).define(["md"], function(md){return(
>                                                                                                         friendly-errors 14:15:59  @
> ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
> 25:0-54 28:26-32  @ ./pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&  @
> ./pages/index.vue  @ ./.nuxt/router.js  @ ./.nuxt/index.js  @
> ./.nuxt/client.js  @ multi eventsource-polyfill
> webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true&timeout=30000&ansiColors=&overlayStyles=&name=client&path=/__webpack_hmr/client
> ./.nuxt/client.js
```

Comment: for which file type?

Comment: binary file type

Answer (score 0):

File loader should do the trick

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/assets/#webpack